# A problem with automatically rounding numbers Python

Tags: python, rounding

I have a small problem and here is my code

```
e = 10**-4 
epsilon = numpy.zeros((10, 0))
epsilon[0] = e
epsilon[0]
```

And here is what I get:

`array([], dtype=float64)`

But I expect 0.0001. It's still the same if I write as

```
 epsilon[0] = epsilon[0] + e
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're creating a 10x0 array which means you don't actually have a location to put the value e into. If you switch to a 10x1 array with epsilon=numpy.zeros((10,1)) your code will produce:

```
array([[0.0001],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ],
       [0.    ]])
```

Though I'm not really sure what your intention is.

Comment: Thank you. Could you have a look at my actual problem below?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Below what? In your question you create 10 lists which each contain 0 elements so when you try to assign to those lists nothing happens. I'm not sure of a 10x1 array meets your needs or what you're trying to accomplish with the array...